# a condition equivalent to compactness in linearly ordered spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, order-topology

Does anyone know where can I find a proof to this proposition:
A linearly ordered topological space is compact if and only if every bounded subset has an infimum and a supremum.

Thank you,

Comment: It seems to me that it doesn't hold. $\mathbb{R}$ is linearly ordered topological space and every bounded subset has infimum and supremum but it's not compact.

Comment: If the space is compact, every subset is bounded. Make the condition that every subset has an infimum and supremum.

Comment: @user87690: The empty set does not have an infimum or supremum in $\mathbb{R}$, but it does in any closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Ah, the empty subset. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See [ProofWiki's proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Subspace_of_Linearly_Ordered_Space) of a slight generalization. Note: any errors in that proof are probably my own.

Comment: Thank you! i will look into it

Answer (score 1):

An "inductive proof" is given in this [short note](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/induction_completeness_brief.pdf).

Comment: I will read it thanks!